# Append a prefix to a input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to "inject" a prefix to an input field value with Jquery so that the input field value would submit as "Referrer Email: {email address}" with {email address} being the dynamic portion. I found the following snippet but am unable to make it work with the other code I have (below) that combines field values into one input. Any ideas?

```
$("#notes").keyup(function(){
var prefix = "Referrer Email: "
if(this.value.indexOf(prefix) !== 0 ){
this.value = prefix + this.value;
}
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#ufirst_name, #ulast_name').on('input', function() {
    $('#recon').val(
      $('#ufirst_name, #ulast_name').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
      }).get().join(' ') /* added space */
    );
  });
});
$(function() {
  $('#uliame').on('input', function() {
    $('#notes').val(
      $('#uliame').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
      }).get().join(' ') /* added space */
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="ufirst_name" placeholder="First Name" id="ulast_name" /><br>
<input type="text" name="ulast_name" placeholder="Last Name" id="ulast_name" />
<br>
<input type="email" name="uliame" placeholder="Email" id="uliame" required onClick="populate()" />
<br>
<input value="Referrer Email" name="Latest_Actions__c" type="text" id="notes" />
<br>
<input value="" name="Referrer_Contact__c" type="text" id="recon" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about to just concatenate `Referrer Email:` to the returned value?

I removed `onClick="populate()"` because I just don't know what this is...

```js
$(function() {

  $('#ufirst_name, #ulast_name').on('input', function() {
    $('#recon').val(
      $('#ufirst_name, #ulast_name').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
      }).get().join(' ') /* added space */
    );
  });

  $('#uliame').on('input', function() {
    $('#notes').val(
      $('#uliame').map(function() {
        return "Referrer Email: "+$(this).val();
      }).get().join(' ') /* added space */
    );
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="ufirst_name" placeholder="First Name" id="ulast_name" /><br>
<input type="text" name="ulast_name" placeholder="Last Name" id="ulast_name" />
<br>
<input type="email" name="uliame" placeholder="Email" id="uliame" required />
<br>
<input value="Referrer Email" name="Latest_Actions__c" type="text" id="notes" />
<br>
<input value="" name="Referrer_Contact__c" type="text" id="recon" />
```

Comment: This is clean and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#notes").keyup(function() {
    var prefix = "Referrer Email: "
    if($(this).val().indexOf(prefix) < 0 ){
        $(this).val(prefix + $(this).val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to find the position of a character not a word.
This should work:

```
$("#notes").keyup(function(){
var prefix = "Referrer Email: "
if (!this.value.startsWith(prefix) ){
this.value = prefix + this.value;
}
});
```

Comment: This does the same thing as OP's code. [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf#Syntax) most definitely searches for a string in a string, not just a single character